# I'm not able to secure flask-admin with my login

Tags: flask

I'm using default flask-admin package and using /admin/admin_login.html for login page. Earlier when i didn't secure my admin then admin was opening without any authentication and i'm able to add, edit, delete any service, review, and faqs.

Without securing admin is not good so, I added a login page which is connected to database and i have user table with added username and hashed password. But, now when i access the admin it still opening without login page authentication but, this time only showing blank admin homepage. Not getting any data from database. And when I try to login through it opens admin panel with blank admin homepage.

Folder Structure

venv
static
--css
--image
--js and more
templates
--admin
---admin_login.html
--includes
--main
app.py
requirements.txt

app.py code below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import os
import pymysql
import time
import threading
import requests
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from flask_admin.form.upload import ImageUploadField
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user, LoginManager
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash


app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'skey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] += 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] += 



# set optional bootswatch theme
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'cerulean'

# Create the SQLAlchemy instance
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)  # This should be hashed, not plaintext!
    

class Service(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'services'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))  
    image = db.Column(db.String(255))    
    nod = db.Column(db.Integer)          
    nop = db.Column(db.Integer)          
    servicename = db.Column(db.String(255))  
    description = db.Column(db.Text)     
    contact = db.Column(db.String(255))  
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255))     


class Review(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reviews'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    service_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user = db.Column(db.String(255))
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))
    comment = db.Column(db.Text)

class Faq(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'faqs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    service_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

def get_next_service_id():
    max_id = db.session.query(db.func.max(Service.id)).scalar()
    return (max_id or 0) + 1

class AuthenticatedAdminView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


      
    
class ServiceView(ModelView):
    
    form_overrides = {
        'image': ImageUploadField
    }
    form_args = {
        'image': {
            'label': 'Image',
            'base_path': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static', 'images', 'services'),
            'allow_overwrite': False
        }
    }
    column_labels = {
        
        'image': 'Image',
        'nod': 'Number of days',
        'nop': 'No of people',
        'servicename': 'Service Name',
        # Add more columns and labels as needed
    }    
    column_list = ['id', 'address', 'image', 'nod', 'nop', 'servicename', 'description', 'contact', 'slug']
    def create_model(self, form):
        service = Service()
        form.populate_obj(service)
        service.id = get_next_service_id()  # Set the ID before saving
        db.session.add(service)
        db.session.commit()
 
service_view = AuthenticatedAdminView(Service, db.session)

class FAQModelView(ModelView):
    column_labels = {
        'title': 'FAQ Heading',
        'description': 'FAQ Discription',        
    }        
    column_list = ('service_id', 'title', 'description')
faq_view = AuthenticatedAdminView(Faq, db.session)      

class ReviewModelView(ModelView):
    column_labels = {
        'user': 'Person Name',
        'comment': 'Review Content',        
    }   
    column_list = ('service_id', 'user', 'address', 'comment')
review_view = AuthenticatedAdminView(Review, db.session)        




db_connection_string = 

engine = create_engine(db_connection_string, connect_args={
    "ssl": {
        "ssl_ca": 

    }
})    

# Get services below
def get_services():
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(text("select * from services"))
        columns = result.keys()
        services = [{column: value for column, value in zip(columns, row)} for row in result]
    return services
# Services end

def get_service_by_slug(slug):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM services WHERE slug = :slug"), {"slug": slug})
        columns = result.keys()
        service = [{column: value for column, value in zip(columns, row)} for row in result]
    return service[0] if service else None


# Get reviews below
def get_reviews(service_id):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(text("select * from reviews where service_id = :service_id"), {"service_id": service_id})
        columns = result.keys()
        reviews = [{column: value for column, value in zip(columns, row)} for row in result]
    return reviews
# Reviews end

# Get FAQs below
def get_faqs(service_id):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(text("select * from faqs where service_id = :service_id"), {"service_id": service_id})
        columns = result.keys()
        faqs = [{column: value for column, value in zip(columns, row)} for row in result]
    return faqs
# FAQs end

admin = Admin(app, name='Admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')
# Add administrative views here

admin.add_view(service_view)
admin.add_view(faq_view)
admin.add_view(review_view)


# Configure Flask-Mail settings
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = ''

app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = ''

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/send-message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    email = request.form.get('email')
    subject = request.form.get('subject')
    message = request.form.get('message')
    datetime = request.form.get('datetime')
    select1 = request.form.get('select1')

    msg = Message(subject, recipients=[''])
    msg.body = f"Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nMessage: {message}\nDate & Time: {datetime}\nSelect1: {select1}"

    mail.send(msg)

    return 'Message sent successfully!'

 
# Configure Flask-Mail settings End


@app.route('/')
def home():
    service = get_services()
    return render_template('main/index.html', service=service)


@app.route('/car-rental')
def car_rental():
    heading = "Car Rental"
    return render_template('main/car-rental.html', heading=heading)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    heading = "About Us"
    return render_template('main/about.html', heading=heading)

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    heading = "Contact Us"
    return render_template('main/contact.html', heading=heading)

@app.route('/services')
def services():
    services = get_services()
    heading = "Services"
    return render_template('main/services.html', service=services, heading=heading)

@app.route('/privacy-policy')
def privacy_policy():
    heading = "Privacy Policy"
    return render_template('main/privacy_policy.html', heading=heading)

@app.route('/terms-and-conditions')
def terms_and_conditions():
    heading = "Terms & Conditions"
    return render_template('main/terms_and_conditions.html', heading=heading)

@app.route('/faqs-and-help')
def faqs_and_help():
    heading = "FAQs & Help"
    return render_template('main/faqs_and_help.html', heading=heading)

@app.route('/service/<path:service_slug>')
def service_details(service_slug):
    service = get_service_by_slug(service_slug)
    if not service:
        # Return a 404 not found error or redirect to another page if the service doesn't exist
        return "Service not found", 404
    service_id = service['id']
    reviews = get_reviews(service_id)
    faqs = get_faqs(service_id)
    

    
    return render_template('main/service_page.html', service=service, reviews=reviews, faqs=faqs)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('admin.index'))
        else:
            flash('Invalid credentials', 'error')
            
    return render_template('admin/admin_login.html')

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    
    # Run the Flask app
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

below is html login form

```
<form action="/admin" method="POST">
        <h3>Login Here</h3>

        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username">

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">

        <button>Log In</button>
        <div class="social">
          <div class="go"><i class="fab fa-google"></i>  Google</div>
          <div class="fb"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>  Facebook</div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want to make like if we login then it will open admin panel with all delete, edit and add feature. If any one open admin panel directly then it will redirect to login page.